# What's the best strategy for describing a transaction in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

In GnuCash, transactions are defined using the fields **Description**, **Notes** and **Memo** (as well as date, currency and amount of course).

The **Description** field appears in any view of a transaction. The **Notes** field appears when you select "Double Line" from the View menu. A **Memo** field appears for each offsetting account when you split a transaction.

Possible contents for the fields are: payee/payer, transaction trigger (what caused the transaction - service, goods, etc), location associated with the transaction, tags/projects/events/people associated with the transaction.

Unfortunately, there is not much guidance neither in the official documentation, nor on the internet on this topic. This is an important question for lay people starting to use GnuCash. The terms **notes** and **memo** have a very similar meaning which might cause some confusion. Also, while personal taste might matter in this question ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GnuCash/comments/i53abq/transaction_descriptions_best_practices/) and [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/53669/118263)), it seems that **consistency** might be the most important answer:

By mixing up the information content that is entered into one field (eg. description is used for the payee in one transaction, and  transaction trigger in another transaction), one might loose information, and the journal ends up being a mess after a few months of working on it.

Furthermore, as pointed out [elsewhere](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/151837/118263), information, such as tags, in the field **memo**, ie on the split line, can affect calculations in reports later on.

What is the best documentation strategy over time?
What information should go in what field in order to 1) define each transaction uniquely and cleanly, 2) not lose information and 3) keep things organized.

Answer (score 3):

They appear in the reports differently. Play with your reports and see what you want to appear where, and based on that use these fields.