# GnuCash: How to build a custom report to show "fixed" vs. "variable" expenses?

Tags: gnucash

I'd like to group expenses into "fixed" (e.g. rent) vs. "variable" (e.g. restaurants) expenses in a report, i.e. probably pick a couple of "accounts" and group them somehow as "fixed" or "variable" respectively.

It seems complicated: https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Custom_Reports#Custom_Reports_in_GnuCash

So maybe it would be easier to export and group account (summaries) in a spreadsheet, rather than trying to get it done within Gnucash?

Open to any suggestions / ideas / solutions.

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/94717/11211 (tagging / multi-category)

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you create 2 placeholder parent accounts under "Expenses", namely, Expenses (Fixed) and Expenses (Variable).

This means the Income Statement will show:

- Expenses:Expenses (Fixed):Rent
- Expenses:Expenses (Variable):Restaurants

Subtotals will be displayed accordingly.